# What would a world with magic realistically look like?

Tags: magic

I'm trying to write a story about a semi-realistic world which takes place after the invention of something along the lines of "[Block Transfer Computations](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Block_Transfer_Computation)" and [the magic of doctor strange](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Magic). But I'm having trouble imagining what would happen, realistically, if sometime around the present, mathematicians figured out that something along the lines of Block Transfer Computations could be readily achieved. This led me to the more question; If magic along the lines of my example were discovered sometime around the present, what would be the most *realistic* consequence of this? Since I'm guessing how this magic works is quite relevant to the answer, what if we found something like the given example, or perhaps something similar to the magic used in "*Doctor strange*"?

Note: By "Sometime around the present", I mean that no later than a day after you're reading this, either mathematicians figure out how to accomplish Block transfer computation, or people from a kind of "Kamar-Taj" present themselves to the world in a way so overt that it can't be waved off (Maybe they prove themselves by sending everyone to the mirror dimension). Also, I'm assuming that the supposed "Explanations" behind either choice of example is valid.

Comment: This sounds very similar to the plot of the [Laundry Files series by Charles Stross](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Laundry_Files). Magic exists and it's applied mathematics. You can solve equations to summon demons or do basically any other magical effect. Computers are mathematical machines, which means you can use them to produce magic effects, too. Magic is also a guarded secret of national agencies. Give a few books a read for the world they have. I personally didn't like the writing, so I dropped the series after a while but it's not awful. The world is pretty interesting.

Comment: An awful lot depends on what portion of the entire population, and what sub-group of the population has the ability to control this magic.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond I'm supposing that in principle anyone can do it, provided they can grasp the mathematics. Since the math would likely be extremely advanced, this would probably limit the group to only those intelligent enough to do the extremely complex calculations in their head.

Comment: At any rate, "how would the world change if X" is *pretty broad*. There is all sort of things that can happen. Each of this is worth writing at least a story. Or a whole series about. The Charles Stross novels have magic relatively obscure as it's normally only reachable by using higher mathematical concepts. But accidents also happen by careless programmers who suddenly find themselves with an algorithm that may summon Cthulhu. Government agencies try to isolate magic users from the rest of the world by employing them. Or disposing of them, if needed.

Comment: @VLAZ I think that magic being widely accessible would inevitably go wrong. For every new person that can use magic, that's one more chance for somebody to mess up or do something messed up. If the whole world has this, that's about 8 billion chances for something to go wrong. But in this case, the availability kind of restricts itself. If this math is more advanced than anything imaginable, then only those capable of such complex calculations could handle it. Magic would be reserved for only the most intelligent, the geniuses amongst geniuses. I'm just not sure what that would look like.

Comment: *"would probably limit the group to only those intelligent enough to do the extremely complex calculations in their head"* // if they have to be able to do it in their head then this precludes using computers to do it or assist you in doing it // if it doesn't then everyone can do it & has access to magic.

Comment: I hate it when they close a question in the middle of my writing up an answer. I should have posted it immediately, and then edited it afterwards. It had to do with it would be just another conspiracy theory, lost in the background of conspiracy theories.

Comment: I would definitely vote to reopen if the scope could be made more manageable.  Try to ask a more specific question like "How would governments regulate magic?" or "How would magic affect the economy?" or "Would the discovery of magic cause another world war?" It would also help if you could establish some scope of how powerful this magic is.  Being able to speak a car out of existence and being able to speak a planet out of existence would have two very different outcomes.

Comment: To build on @Nosajimiki's comment, be a LOT more specific. Asking how "a" government would regulate magic or how it would affect an "economy" is still much too broad. This is what we call a [high concept question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4868/40609) and it's a problem because (a) you're asking us to write your story for you and (b) any reasonable answer could be the size of a book (see [help/on-topic]). SE's model is one-specific-question/one-best-answer. You need to be specific (very specific) and objective.

Comment: You would have to give a very good reason for the discoverers of this 'magic' to reveal it to the world. There is no upside to doing so. Their only chance of longevity would be to form some form of secret society to perpetuate the discovery. Look at how long the US military sat on the technology of building a nuclear reactor so small it fits in a submarine. Secrecy is the most realistic outcome as far as humans are concerned.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond That assumes it is discovered by a government.  Discoveries made by scholars, tinkerers, etc. tend to propagate much faster than they can be restricted.  If a scholar discovered magic, it would probably end up in some scientific journal where it would be learned and tested by thousands of people across the globe before it's general existence is even acknowledged.  Magic will instead spread like computer science, by the time governments even understand it enough to regulate it, you will already have millions of people not only doing it, but determined to open source it.

Comment: Instead the focus of State Sponsored Magic will not be to prevent the spread of magic as to simply try to have the best magic and counter magic.  And the best way to do that is to encourage your populus to embrace general magic use, or else, other nations that embrace it first will outpace you.

Comment: @Nosajimiki You can be sure if this happens, the government will find a way to tax it to death. It will be just another sin tax.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it would look very similar to our current world.

After all, we already use mathematics and computers to do magic (sort of). With the right equations you can make rockets fly. You can generate unfathomably large amounts of energy from special rocks. Communicate sound and image across vast distances. *Even change the weather.*

The difference is, you need more than just those equations. You need a huge amount of infrastructure too. This generally rules out individuals or small groups from harnessing the more destructive aspects of our magic.

In your world this may not be the case. A lone mathematician may discover a special formula which he then uses to hold a nation hostage. Because of this the study of advanced mathematics will be legal only with strict government supervision. Mathematical knowledge will also be heavily guarded. For instance an adept of topology may only be granted access to a particularly advanced theorem after demonstrating decades of loyalty and moral character. Only then would they be escorted to the sealed vaults and naturally any further research on the theorem would have to be performed there.

If computers as well as human mathematicians can produce magic then they too will be a privilege afforded to a more or less select few, depending on how powerful the computer is. Supercomputer arrays would be considered vital government property and extremely closely guarded. High programmers and sysadmins would be very high ranking government officials indeed.

We can also expect there to be agencies endowed with the vast resources and lack of direct oversight to investigate the illegal use of mathematics and various mathemagical cults (the pythagoreans, always up to no good) and conspiracies. All up-and-coming prodigies would be under continuous monitoring and they and their families may be "forced" to live in special government sanctioned housing (suitably luxurious of course).

Freedom of knowledge would be a very foreign idea as would scientific/mathematical/magical journals. Academia would be organized much more hierarchically (if it is possible to imagine such a thing). How much knowledge one has hoarded would be the mark of a distinguished scholar instead of how widely they are cited. This all means that mathematics as well as magitech would probably advance much more slowly in this world. There would be no "scientific" revolutions, instead just very, very cautious and incremental advancements. After all this "calculus-craft" seems harmless, but who knows what apocalyptic incantations it might be developed into.

Comment: Realistically, how would we even know? It would become just another tin-foil-hat conspiracy theory, and blend in with every other alien abduction themed conspiracy theory, and dismissed by most people.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond I'm not sure if you meant to post that comment on another post or if I'm just having trouble understanding what you mean...

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond  In my question (which I will edit to be more focused), I specified that either mathematicians revealed it publicly, or pre-existing "Mathemagicians" from a Kamar-Taj sort of temple introduced it far too overtly to be waved away. I could see how the former case could be drowned out in conspiracy, but in the latter, if they did something like transporting everyone to the mirror dimension, or launching some magical terrorist attack, caught in 4K by every major news organization, that would be *very* difficult to dismiss.

Comment: You said in your answer "I suspect it would look very similar to our current world." Methinks it would probably make so little difference in our world, very few people would notice. We have so many other conspiracy theories, it would just add to the background noise. I had elaborated on this in an answer, but it was closed before I could post it. If it were in a world of 
 current humans, most people would dismiss it. And, frankly, the perpetrators would never let the secret out. No upside to doing so.